# vue onclick function inside appended html not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events, jquery-events

I'm having problem using @click vue function inside an appended HTML element using a Vue component.

The component have two button to add and remove divs inside a container, as follow:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" @click.prevent.stop="addQuestion()">Add Question</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click.prevent.stop="removeQuestion()" v-if="notRemovableQuestion">Remove Question</button>
  </div>
```

addQuestion function is as follow:

```
addQuestion(){
  var newQuestion = '<div class="questionBox col-md-12 f-left p-2 mt-2" style="border:2px solid blue;">' +
                      '<div class="col-md-11 f-left">' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="domanda" placeholder="Question" v-model="domanda" />' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="question_description" placeholder="Question Description" v-model="question_description" />' +
                        '<div class="form-check">' +
                          '<div class="newAnswerActions f-left full-width col-md-12 mb-2 mt-2">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" @click.native="addAnswer()">Add Answer</a>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click.native="removeAnswer()" v-if="notRemovableAnswer">Remove Answer</a>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<label class="form-check-label">' +
                            '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="risposte" id="exampleRadios1" value="">' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer" placeholder="Risposta" />' +
                          '</label>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="col-md-1 f-left">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @click.prevent.stop="removeQuestion()">SAVE</button>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

  $(".allQuestionContainer").append(newQuestion); }
```

The new container is successfully appended but the two buttons for Add Answer and Remove Answer, calling @click.native="addAnswer()" and @click.native="removeAnswer()" are not working. I've tried with or without native and anything else, also with js onClick but no luck, the function is never reached and the click event it's not working.

What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: In short, you're adding content to the page **after** the Vue instance has registered itself so the newly added props aren't reactive. I'm sure this has been answered somewhere before so I'll dig around and look.

Comment: forgot to mention that the addQuestion function is inside the export default { methods: { addQuestion(){ // code above } }

Comment: Out of interest, why are you mixing Vue and JQuery in this way? This can be done with pure vue and that would mean everything would link up correctly ..

Comment: do you have an example of a correct way to only use vue? I haven't found something like append in vue so I mixed but I'm quite sure it's not the best way...

Comment: I'll jot up an answer with some points on what could be changed to make it work.

Comment: thank you @webnoob, waiting for it, no hurry :) wish you a good christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid the course you are taking and make use of components instead.

Rather than appending HTML to a div, you could create a component which contains the HTML you're currently assigning to `newQuestion`. That component would then be responsible for dealing with the `addQuestion` and `removeQuestion` methods and because it's a component registered with Vue, it'll automatically be reactive.

Once the component is registered you can control whether it's shown by doing something like:

```
<new-question v-if="showNewQuestion"></new-question>
```

Then within your `addQuestion` method you just set `this.showNewQuestion = true` so that the component will show. `showNewQuestion` would obviously need to be declared within your `data` prop and defaulted to false.

I've not gone into great detail about the formation of the component as I don't know if your using `vue-loader` or not but more information can be found on the [Vue Docs Site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Comment: ok..thank you! I'm now using a component for the newQuestion part and Vue.extend to load it. Then I'm using vm.$mount to render it into a div.